# CSS acts weirdly on pages that are not the index

Tags: css, menu

For some reason my css is acting weirdly on pages that are not the index. 
Which is weird because the whole top part of the webpage is a shared include between all of them.

Here is a pic of the problem and the relevant code:

[image]

Top part of pages: http://pastebin.com/qePqZhsE

navbar.php: http://pastebin.com/7065Dxcy

Css for navbar: http://pastebin.com/79tdQ4eP

It has to be something in the CSS, because the rest is identical but I don't see it. (though I might just be lacking too much sleep :P)

Comment: Are your other files in subdirectories ? If so the css file may simply not be found.

Comment: The css is in /includes but the broken pages are in the same folder as the index. And all of the CSS works except for those things being red.

Comment: @Coolcrab Can you provide a link to your site?

Comment: @Abody97 http://trulyscience.com and http://trulyscience.com/test/empty.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
ul.dropdown li.hover a { color: red; }
```

with

```
ul.dropdown li:hover a { color: red; }
```

on line 12 in css file

EDIT:

As said in the comment below, You have a structure like this: "ul.dropdown > li > ul > li > a" qhile you are applying css to "ul.dropdown li a".

So, try replacing

```
ul.dropdown li.hover a
```

with

```
ul.dropdown > li > ul > li.hover a
```

or remove at all.

Comment: That also broke the ones on the index.

Comment: Well, it proves that you have to do something with the lines, which have word :hover in them. Try removing "li:hover a" lines for instance, as you already have "a:hover", or similar.

Comment: removing `ul.dropdown li:hover a {color:red }` seems to do it. I have no idea why though.

Comment: great that helped :) It is cause Your dropdown is inside another li element (you have a structure like this: ul.dropdown > li > ul > li > a and in the same time, you are applying css to ul.dropdown li a). Thus, when You place Your mouse over the dropdown, this line initiates.

Answer (score 1):

Simply, the issue is that the navbar's structure in your PHPs other than `index` is different, here's a screenshot of the structure of your navbar in `index.php`:

[image: Navbar in index]

In `empty.php`:

[image: Navbar in empty.php]

Just make sure you're using the same structure, I guess; hope that helped!